# Finding object using findViewById with string always returns null

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid

I'm trying to find an object using findViewById with a string using this line

```
Slots[i][j] = requireActivity().findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(builder.toString(), "id", requireActivity().getPackageName()));
```

but when it runs, it always returns null. When I print the id that it uses it prints something like 2131231288 when the real id value is 1000072. I've checked to make sure that the string is correct and is the same as the id. Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Given the `requireActivity()` calls, it looks like this is in a `Fragment`. If so, then you need to call `findViewById()` on the `Fragment`'s `View`, not on the `Activity`.

Comment: I can't believe it was so simple. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Mr_ME23 - You should not have tagged this question with `[android-studio]`.  It is not about the IDE you are using.  It is about the platform you are building your app for; i.e. `[android]`.  In future, read the tag wikis for the tags that you use.